# Can we use "neither...and...."?

Tags: grammar

Is it correct to use **neither ... and ....** ?

For example: *Neither* Ema *and* Jane achieved the highscore.

I have recently participated in an IELTS mock exam, I had written: Neither of Ema and Jane achieved the highscore. The examiner commented that it is: *Neither Ema and Jane achieved the highscore*.

But I after their comment I remebered I have always studied " either... or", "neither...nor". So, I wonder if the examiner sentence is correct or not. I searched on the Internet and all samples and grammar explanations I found had used the structure of **neither ... nor ...** .

Is it wrong (or uncommon) to use **and** with **neither**?

Comment: Thanks alot. Also, As the answer of your question: No, I am not sure about the dictation of names, because I have chosen those names myself.

Comment: Your examiner was 100% wrong! :)

Comment: @annabeth: Could you please explain it? Do you mean we must write "Neither Ema nor Jane achieved the highscore"? or you meant "Neither of Ema and Jane achieved the highscore" (one of the answers here at this page had told that it is correct, I was waiting for the reaction of others to understand that it is correct or not. But unfortunately it is seemed that it is deleted now.

Comment: You can refer to swmcdonnell’s answer for a more detailed explanation. The short answer is that you can **never** say “Neither ___ and ___”.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Neither" is a conjunction used with "nor" to connect two negative alternatives. The example, "Neither Emma and Jane," is incorrect. The correct usage is "Neither Emma nor Jane..."

It's a little less formal and found more in spoken English, but you can use "and" with "not either" or "neither." For example:

> Ema didn't achieve a high score and Jane didn't either.

> Ema didn't achieve a high score and neither did Jane.

Source: [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/neither-neither-nor-and-not-either_2)

Comment: Is this the only way of using "and" with "neither? Can we reform it in anyway to use "and Jane" before finishing the first sentence? (I mean before: Ema didn't achieve a high score)

Comment: You can say "Emma and Jane didn't achieve high scores." Otherwise, the correct usage is "Neither Emma nor Jane achieved a high score."